# Why wouldn't the standard library implement collect on an array-of-tuples's iterator without cloned()?

Tags: rust

This code works:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let result: HashMap<&str, &str> = [("name", "Luke")].iter().cloned().collect();

    println!("{:?}", &result);
}
```

It doesn't if I remove the call to `cloned()`:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::collections::HashMap<&str, &str>: std::iter::FromIterator<&(&str, &str)>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:4:65
  |
4 |     let result: HashMap<&str, &str> = [("name", "Luke")].iter().collect();
  |                                                                 ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `std::collections::HashMap<&str, &str>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&(&str, &str)`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<&(&str, &str)>` is not implemented for `std::collections::HashMap<&str, &str>`
```

My understanding is that the standard library implements lots of things for tuples but not this case? Why wouldn't it compile like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full error message has more information that is useful:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::collections::HashMap<&str, &str>: std::iter::FromIterator<&(&str, &str)>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:4:65
  |
4 |     let result: HashMap<&str, &str> = [("name", "Luke")].iter().collect();
  |                                                                 ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `std::collections::HashMap<&str, &str>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&(&str, &str)`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<&(&str, &str)>` is not implemented for `std::collections::HashMap<&str, &str>`
```

Your code without `.cloned()` is trying to make a `HashMap` from an iterator of references to tuples, but the [`HashMap::from_iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#impl-FromIterator%3C(K,%20V)%3E) method requires an iterator of owned tuples. The `.cloned()` call turns the iterator of references into an iterator of owned tuples that can be given to `HashMap::from_iter()` (which is what `.collect()` will end up calling)

The reason that the standard library doesn't implement `HashMap::from_iter()` for an iterator of tuple references is because `HashMap` needs to own the tuple to get the key and value from it, which is impossible if it is passed a reference to a tuple.

Comment: Could you address OP's question on **why** the standard library doesn't implement `FromIter` for references of tuples?

Comment: Much appreciated. Why can't it use ref tuple's values though? This works: `let tup = &(&1, &2); println!("{:?}", tup.0);`

Comment: @YuriGeinish, the only reason that works is because integers implement the `Copy` trait so they can be copied out of references. If you try with something else like `String`, you get an error https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=303f6ec8190aa7b1794cfef579e5003d&version=stable

Comment: You're right. Like it says, it would be moving out of borrowed content. Can't `HashMap` work around that by borrowing the tuple's values?

Comment: @YuriGeinish: No. You don't tell `HashMap` how to store the key and value, it *may* store them in an array of tuples or it *may* use one array for keys and one array for values. If all it had was a reference to the tuples, how would it then tease apart the key from the value? This would require cloning, and Rust being about explicitness errs on the side of making cloning visible to the client.